# Catch Registry request C++

Tags: c++, winapi, registry, hook

I known such tools
http://portableapps.com/development/projects/registry_rapper

RegRap.exe can get through param other .exe file and catch requests to registry and save it into .ini

That is good, but I need snippt code to set such hundler inside my C++ program and for given Reg KEY return my value...

RegRap.exe written with NSIS scripts that is why is not helpful for me :(

But may be somebody known other project only with c++?

Thx, and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post seems to say that there are no hooks for the registry and you can only long poll. [Simple way to hook registry access for specific process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349029/simple-way-to-hook-registry-access-for-specific-process)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to track registry access within YOUR program, you can #define away the registry API functions, provide your hooks instead, and track it in your hooks.

```
//in your stdafx.h, or some other universally included file
#define RegCreateKeyEx MyRegCreateKeyEx


//somewhere else
#undef RegCreateKeyEx

LONG WINAPI MyRegCreateKeyEx(stuff...)
{
  //Track
  //Call the real RegCreateKeyEx
}
```

That's probably the easiest way of hooking an API. Will not work if you want to track registry usage by your program but outside of your code (i. e. in libraries or DLLs). Then more advanced techniques are in order.

Also, consider Process Monitor by Mark Russinovich: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

It's not a programmatic hook, but an awesome tool all around, and therefore worth plugging. It monitors registry access by your process(es) and then some.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use pure C++, check out the libraries [EasyHook](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/) and [Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/). Both are intended for this sort of function-level hooking. EasyHook works in C++ and C#, 32 and 64-bit, while Detours is somewhat outdated and only for 32-bit C++ (even running it on a 64-bit OS can crash your program).

You need to install the hook within the target process, either by loading your code as a DLL or creating the process (suspended), installing the hooks and then running it.

In EasyHook that goes something like:

```
LhInstallHook(&RegCreateKeyEx, &MyRegCreateKeyEx, &hookstruct);
```

You can also hook functions your library is *not* linked to using the Windows API to get the address.